# Should I apply for a Schengen or UK visa first?

Tags: visas, uk, schengen, indian-citizens

I have planned a short trip to Europe for 2 weeks. I am from India. The itinerary is New Delhi - - > London (4 days) - - > Amsterdam (3 days) - - > Prague (2 days) - - > Vienna  (2 days) - - > Budapest (2 days)- - > New Delhi).

As the starting point of my trip is London, should I apply for a UK visa first? Or is it advisable to apply for a Schengen visa first?

This is my first international trip. So I want to be sure of the best possible way.

Comment: It doesn't matter.

Comment: Can you adjust your itinerary if you get a refusal from one of your destinations? Since you plan to spend most of your trip in the Schengen area I’d apply there first followed by your UK application.

Comment: Consider how easy it will be to get the two visas.  E.g. if you can get an invitation from someone in the UK but not the Schengen area then that visa will probably be easier.  Get it first and having it should make the other easier.  We have many friends and family who visit us in the UK and make side trips to the Schengen area.  We always advise them to get the UK visa first as we can offer them an invitation.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am visiting UK to watch football. So, the itinerary can be adjusted based on the situation.

Answer (score 4):

In general, you should always apply for visas in *reverse* order of your itinerary. That is, apply first for the visa of the last country you visit or transit, and apply last for the visa of the first country you visit or transit.

This is because countries in the middle of your itinerary will want to know that you can lawfully enter the next country on your itinerary. This is of particular importance for Schengen visas; if you can't demonstrate that you can lawfully enter the next country on your itinerary, and that you have the money to do so, your visa may be refused.